# Spring Cron expression to trigger at every 6 months

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cronexpression, crontrigger

How to write cron expression to trigger a function on every 6 month at 16 pm  in the evening?

Answer (score 5):

0 0 16 1 1/6 ? *

CronMaker can help you in the future. 
http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick `0 0 16 1 1/7 ?`

Comment: I guess we will know in 6 months :)

Answer (score 0):

0 0 16 ? 1/6 MON#1 *

To execute the first monday of every six months

next execution date :

1. Monday, July 7, 2014 4:00 PM
2. Monday, January 5, 2015 4:00 PM
3. Monday, July 6, 2015 4:00 PM
4. Monday, January 4, 2016 4:00 PM
5. Monday, July 4, 2016 4:00 PM